# Unity Facebook SDK 4.3.4 - AccessToken and Login Status not cleared for previous user

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-access-token, facebook-unity-sdk

I just wanted to see if anyone else have seen this problem, or whether I may be doing something incorrectly.  That is, after logging out from the Facebook app and logging in as another person (either through Facebook app directly, or FB.Login via the Unity app), you will still get the profile data for the previous person (access token, login status, userId, etc).

After FB.Init(), FB.IsLoggedIn is still true and FB.UserId and FB.AccessToken is still present for the previous user.  Even after a forced FB.Login(), FB.AccessToken and FB.UserId is still the previous users.  Only when the app is uninstalled, will the new user be returned.

I've managed to reproduce this with InteractiveConsole example app, deployed on an Android Nexus 7 device.  I've also filed a bug report on Facebook, but couldn't tag it with "Unity SDK" since the bug report form only has radio buttons for tags, and "Unity SDK" isn't one of the selections.

Hope to catch the attention of devs here, or see if anyone has seen this or not.  Detailed reproduction steps are here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/593522247373530

Comment: Hi Simon. We've made an internal task to look into this, fix coming soon, thanks for reporting it!

Comment: @aaron: JohnnyMyhre had a question on this. His comment will get deleted soon because it is not an answer but he might check up on this post and I will leave a message for him as well. The question: http://i.imgur.com/81NF5Im.png